# How to drop tracks when concatenating with mkvmerge?

Tags: bash, shell, video, merge, mkv

I have two video files. One file has 4 tracks, one file has 3 tracks:

```
'/home/usr/vids/E01.mkv' track 0: Using the output module for the format 'PCM'.
'/home/usr/vids/E01.mkv' track 2: Using the output module for the format 'AVC/H.264'.
'/home/usr/vids/E01.mkv' track 3: Using the output module for the format 'SSA/ASS text subtitles'.
'/home/usr/vids/E02.mkv' track 0: Using the output module for the format 'PCM'.
'/home/usr/vids/E02.mkv' track 1: Using the output module for the format 'SSA/ASS text subtitles'.
'/home/usr/vids/E02.mkv' track 2: Using the output module for the format 'AVC/H.264'.
'/home/usr/vids/E02.mkv' track 3: Using the output module for the format 'SSA/ASS text subtitles'
```

I am trying to append these two files using the following `mkvmerge` command:

```
mkvmerge -o '/home/usr/vids/combined.mkv' -s und,eng --append-to 1:2:0:2,1:0:0:0,1:3:0:3 '/home/usr/vids/E01.mkv' + '/home/usr/vids/E02.mkv'
```

Now I am controlling the track mapping using `--append-to 1:2:0:2,1:0:0:0,1:3:0:3`. However, file `E02.mkv` has an extra subtitle track. This causes `mkvmerge` to throw the following error:

> Error: Only partial append mappings were given for the file no. 1
> ('/home/usr/vids/E02.mkv'). Either don't specify any mapping (in which
> case the default mapping will be used) or specify a mapping for all
> tracks that are to be copied.

I do not care about this extra subtitle track. I would like to drop this extra subtitle track. **How can I do this?**